# Ruby: get correct types on values in query string

Tags: ruby, types, query-string

Say I have

```
str = "a=2&b=3.05&c=testing"
```

I run

```
require 'cgi'
out = {}
CGI::parse(str).each { |k,v| out[k] = v[0] }
```

When I output `a`, 2 is a `string`, when I want it to be an `Int`

```
out['a'] // "2" (instead of int 2)
out['b'] // "3.05" (instead of float 3.05)
```

Is there any way to correct the types from the query string?

**Update:**

Added this method to test for numbers

```
def is_a_number?(s)
  s.to_s.match(/\A[+-]?\d+?(\.\d+)?\Z/) == nil ? false : true 
end
```

and during the parse

```
CGI::parse(url).each do |k,v|
    val = v[0]
    if is_a_number? val 
        val = val.include?('.') ? val.to_f : val.to_i
    end 
    out[k] = val 
end
```

Seems to work with basic examples. Is there anything unsafe about this?

Comment: You only get strings as query values. This is to simplify the HTTP conversations/queries/transactions. Imagine the fun we'd have if native binary representations of integers and reals were getting thrown around from non-heterogeneous systems. As a result, you have to have knowledge of the type of the value being received, which you *should* have, since you're on the server side of the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited:** This works

```
require 'cgi'

str = "a=2&b=3.05&c=testing"
out = {}

def typecasted(str)
  [str.to_i, str.to_f, str].find { |cast| cast.to_s == str }
end

CGI::parse(str).each do |key, val|
  out[key] = typecasted val.first
end

p out
# => {"a"=>2, "b"=>3.05, "c"=>"testing"}
```

Comment: have you tested ? 2 errors, typecasted has to be defined first and then i get `typecasted': undefined method `to_i' for ["2"]:Array (NoMethodError)

Comment: Doesn't handle boolean

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no, there's no way to just get the correct type out.  You could write your own parser that tries to guess based on regex matches.  The typical way this is handled is that you parse them manually based on the expected type of each parameter.  You can call methods like `to_i` and `to_f` to convert them to the types you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you parse it like this you shouldn't have a problem

```
out = {}
CGI::parse(str).each do |k, v|
  v, v = (v = v.first), (v if v[/[a-zA-Z]/]) || [v.to_i, v.to_f].max
  out.merge!(Hash[k, v])
end
```

Combined with the technique of AJcodez this gives

```
out = {}
CGI::parse(str).each do |k, v|
  v, out[k] = (v = v.first), [v.to_i, v.to_f, v].find { |c| c.to_s == v }
end
```

Or as a one-liner

```
Hash[*CGI::parse(str).map {|k, v| v = v.first; [k, [v.to_i, v.to_f, v].find { |c| c.to_s == v }]}.flatten]
```

gives

```
{"a"=>2, "b"=>3.05, "c"=>"testing"}
```

Comment: As @starship mentioned above, you probably don't want to use `eval()`.  We're talking about CGI parameters from the web here.  This is very dangerous from a security standpoint.

Comment: Doesn't handle boolean.

Answer (score -1):

I can't think of a way with that input string you have, but if you can change that to

```
str = "a=2&b=3.05&c='testing'"
```

(notice the single quotes), you could use the **eval** function on each value and let ruby guess the types.

Comment: I don't think using eval is a good choice, someone _slightly_ clever could abuse it if they knew you're using eval. It is better to expect types like Jim suggested; simply avoid zeroes (use -1, for example) to make sure it was parsed right, since `String#to_i` returns 0 if it can't convert a string to an integer. If you have to, you could use regexp and "flag" for possible types, but definitely not `eval`.